# How do I show that these are bijective actions?

Tags: group-actions

I have the following problem:

We fix a group G and a set X. I have just shown the following two statements.

1. Let $a:G\times X\rightarrow X$ be a left action of G on X. Show that the map $b:X\times G\rightarrow X, b(x,g)=a(g^{-1},x)=g^{-1}x$  defines a right action of G on X
2. Let $b:X\times G\rightarrow X$ be a right action of G on X. Show that the map $a:G\times X\rightarrow X, a(g,x)=b(x,g^{-1})=xg^{-1}$  defines a left action of G on X

And now I need to show the following:

> Show that the constructions in 1.,2. are inverses of each other and define bijections between the sets of right and left actions of G on X.

I really don't understand what they want, so do i first need to show that $a(b(x,g))=b(x,g)$ and $(b(a(g,x))=a(g,x)$?

Furthermore I don't see why I need to define multiple bijections, not only one?

Can please someone give me a hint for both question and maybe explain better what I need to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a group $G$ and a set $X$, you can consider the set $L$ of all left actions of $G$ on $X$, and similarly, you can consider the set $R$ for right actions. You have constructed maps $f: L \to R$ and $g: R\to L$, defined by $f(a(g,x)) = b(x, g^{-1})$ and similarly for $g$. Now it remains to show that $g \circ f$ is the identity map on $L$, i.e. it sends a left action to itself, and similarly, to show that $f\circ g$ is the identity map on $R$. Note that you are only constructing a bijection of *sets*, rather than an isomorphism of groups or an isomorphism of $G$-sets.

One thing that may be getting in the way of this is the terminology that is being used for this problem - you may be confusing the *maps* $f: L \to R$ and the *group action* $a: G \times X \to X$. To show, for example, that $g\circ f$ is the identity map on $L$, take any group action $a: G\times X \to X$, and show that for all $x \in X, g\in G$, that $g\circ f(a(g,x)) = a(g,x)$.

Comment: sorry but as I see this, then I haven't constructet your $a:L\rightarrow R$?

Comment: Edited for clarity - you've constructed the maps $L \to R$ via the constructions in parts (1) and (2) in the question.

Comment: ah okey but now I have just constructed this two bijections between L and R and this shows immediately that 1. and 2. are inverses right?

Comment: One needs to prove that $f$ and $g$ as written are actually inverse to each other. It's straightforward but not an immediate statement.

Comment: perfect thanks!